# How to optimize and make the code more readable

Tags: javascript, optimization

I barely managed to write this code, though it does its work almost correctly. Nevertheless, I really need your help to make it more readable and meaningful.\

P.S.
OMG I've added tons of comment, but algorithms of the stackoverflow decided that I need to, no, no... I have to add some more useless text here. So Algorithms of the Stackoverflow, is this enough?\

P.P.S.
sorry...

```js
//creating tree of user's properties

//getting users
const request = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", request);
xhr.send();
//when got users render them
xhr.onload = () => {
  //getting the root element
  const root = document.getElementById("root");
  //parsing them into the object
  JSON.parse(xhr.response).forEach((user) => {
    //=========================================
    //creating ul tag for each user <ul>
    const ul = document.createElement("ul");
    //iterating each users properties
    for (const property in user) {
      // ====================================
      // for each property of a user creating li tag <li>
      const listItem = document.createElement("li");
      const value = user[property];
      // if any property instance of Object,
      // then render propery : value
      if (!(user[property] instanceof Object)) {
        listItem.innerHTML = `${property}: ${value}`;
      } else {
        //else if property is Object render just name of the property
        listItem.innerHTML = `${property}:`;
      }
      // I know that this "if" statement is peace of unacceptable code
      // that's why I'm here to ask you for help
      if (user[property] instanceof Object) {
        //========================================
        //we have 2 Object props, address and company
        //here we catch them and iterate each property
        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(user, property)) {
          //=========================================
          //creating mini-child ul tag for address and company
          const ulmini = document.createElement("ul");
          //for each prop of adress or company creating newListItem that is <li> tag
          for (const prop in value) {
            const newItem = value[prop];
            const newListItem = document.createElement("li");
            newListItem.innerHTML = `${prop}: ${newItem}`;
            //append all <li> tags
            ulmini.appendChild(newListItem);
          }
          listItem.appendChild(ulmini);
        }
      }
      //appending user's all properties
      ul.appendChild(listItem);
    }
    // appending all list of users
    root.appendChild(ul);
  });
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>doc</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"So Algorithms of the Stackoverflow, is this enough?"_ - Instead of adding unnecessary rubbish have a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/) which should explain why the _"algorithms"_ expect more text than _"I barely managed..."_

Comment: Code reviews are the topic of https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Instead of working around the messages you were getting shown, did you consider reading them?

Comment: Seeing how he is new to the platform he might have missed the messages, I hope he will post it at the correct place with the correct format next time, but asking like that might scare new people away. Not trying to start anything just wanted to voice my opinion. @Liam

Comment: Next time, please pay attention to what the content warnings are saying, instead of finding clever ways to make them be quiet. The system was trying to ask you to be more specific about what you thought could use improvement, or why - tossing in arbitrary text like you did just says "I don't care about the rules" to everyone that spends a lot of time curating the site. Please don't do that again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question should actually be posted on [codereview.stackoverflow.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

But to answer, comments are a matter of personal preference or company standards.

Personaly I would do something like this:

Not entirely sure if `/**` is posible here but otherwise I would use something like this: `//***`

```
/**
 *
 * Insert big description for what the code should do as a whole
 *
 */

const request = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", request);
xhr.send();
xhr.onload = () => {
  const root = document.getElementById("root");

  JSON.parse(xhr.response).forEach((user) => {
    const ul = document.createElement("ul");

    for (const property in user) {
      const listItem = document.createElement("li");
      const value = user[property];

      /**
       * Subhead description for code underneath
       */
      if (!(user[property] instanceof Object)) {
        listItem.innerHTML = `${property}: ${value}`;
      } else {
        listItem.innerHTML = `${property}:`;
      }


      /**
       * Subhead description for code underneath
       */
      if (user[property] instanceof Object) {
        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(user, property)) {
          const ulmini = document.createElement("ul");

          for (const prop in value) {
            const newItem = value[prop];
            const newListItem = document.createElement("li");
            newListItem.innerHTML = `${prop}: ${newItem}`;
            ulmini.appendChild(newListItem);
          }

          listItem.appendChild(ulmini);
        }
      }
      ul.appendChild(listItem);
    }
    root.appendChild(ul);
  });
};
```

In terms of the code itself, it is already pretty clean/short so I wouldn't recommend changing it if it works.